# Simple server for Unity games

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, server, client-server

Are there any existing services which could help built a simple server for a Unity game? All I want is to make an app to request and receive an image and some text from the web and show it to users. So when I change the image and the text on the server side, all my apps will display new pic and text. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can simply place your image and the text you want on a standard webserver, then you can use Unity's WWW class to access it. For example, "http://example.com/unitygametext.txt" and "http://example.com/image.png".

Unity's documentation has [some examples on how to get textures and text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html):

```
IEnumerator Start() {
    using (WWW www = new WWW("http://example.com/image.png")) {
        yield return www;
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

For text you just have to replace `WWW.texture` with `WWW.text`.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are asking for is just a http server, you can connect to you server using the [WWW Class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)